# Cut & paste of file : C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, copy-paste

In C# the easiest way, to Cut+Paste myself(exe program) from `c:\data` to `c:\data2` if i click on a button in VS windows forms app ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way an executing application can move itself.

What you could do is:

Suppose you have:

- `A - Executing Application.`
- `B - Spawned Application.`

Now:

1. `A` is executing.
2. `A` creates another app called `B`.
3. `A` shuts down.
4. `B` moves `A` from `Data` to `Data2`.
5. `B` starts `A` from new location.
6. `B` shuts down.

Comment: yes this is somehow what i had in mind, thank you, i will try to figure it how to work this out

Comment: @Tom: That's the only option I could think of... :)

Answer (score 1):

You can [File.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a.aspx) to transfer the file from one folder to another. For example...

```
File.Copy("C:\Data\MyProgram.exe", "C:\Data2\MyProgram.exe"
```

Taz suggested that the file won't copy as it's executing and that's something to watch out for, but I've been able to copy running programs before.

Comment: c# is such a nice language :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way. I don't think it is possible as the file is executing.

Comment: What if its copied first and than exe closes and deletes itself ?

Comment: After it has finished it can delete itself.(Because it is already closed)